# Pruning the users table

Tags: database, mysql, query

I have a site that deals exclusively with user generated content.

After a few years, the users table is getting to a stage where it can probably be pruned of folk who have registered but not actually submitted any content.

What query would I run to show the users who have zero posts?

I thought something like `select id from craft_users where id not in (select distinct authorId from craft_entries)` would do it.

The `distinct` query certainly returns 1020 rows where we actually have around 1800 users.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will do the trick

```
select * from craft_users
left join craft_entries on craft_users.id = craft_entries.authorId
where craft_entries.authorId is null and craft_users.id <> "1"
```

Comment: You probably don't want to delete the results of that query from the `craft_users` table, though.  Take the `id` from the results and delete the matching `id`s from the `craft_elements` table.  The cascading deletes on the foreign keys will take of cleanup up the relevant rows in the related tables.